# Unexpected result for is.finite() for data frames in R

Tags: r

I've used `is.finite()` for vectors, matrices, etc., and it works well.  What I'm puzzled about is why it seems to return `FALSE` for data frames and lists.

For instance, the following example:

```
m <- matrix(0, 3, 3)
d <- as.data.frame(m)

is.finite(m)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
[2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
[3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE

is.finite(d)
   V1    V2    V3 
FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Fairly naturally, it has the same behavior for lists.

I can understand if a function doesn't work for a particular type of object (e.g. data frames).  Other than the trivial case ("a stopped clock is right twice a day" --> a matrix with non-finite values), I can't see a case where `is.finite()` should return anything meaningful for a data frame or a list.  I'd expect an error instead of `FALSE`, or else expect it to coerce the input to, say, a matrix, before applying the function.

The question: is there some way to use `is.finite()` in a meaningful way with data frames (and lists), or is there something about its behavior for which it makes more sense to return `FALSE` than an error?

---

Note 1: By the way, this is in the documentation:

```
 All elements of types other than logical, integer, numeric and complex vectors
 are false.  Complex numbers are finite if both the real and imaginary parts are.
```

So, to clarify the question: why return a false, rather than an error?  The effect is that one has to add type checking outside of a call to `is.finite()`.

Note 2: Just to address a usage case: I was considering using `is.na()`, `is.nan()`, and `is.infinite()` for checking some numerical anomalies, and decided that `is.finite()` would do the trick, until I realized that it does not behave in the same was for data frames as `is.na()`.  This discrepancy was unexpected.

---

Update (2011-11-01): R 2.14.0 has been released and its NEWS file reports: `The default methods for is.finite(), is.infinite() and is.nan() now signal an error if their argument is not an atomic vector.` Thanks, R-Core gods!  (NB: Kohske earlier reported this would be the case, as stated in the development version.  The news is that now it is this is now the release version.)

Comment: When using with `list`, `is.na` is elementwise, while `is.nan`, `is.inifinite`, `is.finte` is not. `NA` is special since the value is missing. Other three, nan, finite, and infinite is description about the existing value. `NA` is not a mathematical concept, while other three are relevant to arithmetic operation in computing.

Comment: @kohske Can you submit that as an answer?  I believe that is correct.  I had not looked for element-wise properties.  I also corrected a mistake about `is.nan`. FWIW, `is.finite()` passes to a C99 function (as mentioned in documentation), so, as you suggest, the only R-specific checking is done by `is.na()`.

Comment: Mistake, if `x` is `list`, `is.na(x)` and `is.nan(x)` behave in a similar way. if `x` is `data.frame`, the behaviors are different.

Comment: @kohske: Aha, I remember that lists are what I'd initially tested to see `is.nan` behave that way.  There are lots of little gotchas here.

Comment: I think the distinction that "works" is between `is` methods that test mode-ism which are vector-wise and other methods that test element-wise aspects.

Comment: Just follow up. In the next version of R (2.14.0), using `is.finite()` etc with non atomic vector will induce an error. http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/html/NEWS.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a vector of list to a function that is documented to deliver expected results with vectors of logical, integer, numeric and complex elements and to return FALSE with anything else. You should be doing something like this:

```
> sapply( d, is.finite)
       V1   V2   V3
[1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
[2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
[3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

(BTW: dataframes are just lists with extra attributes.)

It might be helpful to compare the results to how `is.nan` behaves. Both `is.nan` and `is.finite` are element-wise features. Also look at how tests for mode (which is not what `is.finite` or `is.nan` test) offer. These give list-wise results for `is.character`, `is.numeric`, and `is.logical`.

```
> sapply(d, is.character)
   V1    V2    V3 
FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: This seems to be a good workaround, it could be wrapped as `my.is.finite()`, but the underlying question (which I've attempted to clarify) is whether the FALSE is reasonable for something that seems to be an extension of functions like `is.na`.

Comment: I think that it is at this point a philosophic question. The function behave as documented, so you will need to argue any changes in the "court" of R-Core at the venue of the r-devel mailing list. There's nothing we can do here to offer you satisfaction.

Comment: I try not to disturb the R-Core gods.  :)  Btw, take a look at Kohske's comment - the answer seems to be the underlying elementwise approach; this, plus the outsourcing to a C99 function, seems to explain the different behaviors.  As for `FALSE`, I suppose one can blame the C code.  To get element-wise results, your `sapply` seems to be the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know why it wouldn't return an error.  Unfortunately, `is.finite(as.numeric(d))` returns an error (`Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`).  So, the only thing that occurs to me is to iterate through the columns (which do work correctly with `is.finite()`) like so:

```
df.is.finite=function(d)
{
  for (i in 1:ncol(d))
  {
    if(!(all(is.finite(d[,i]))))
    {
      return(FALSE)
    }
  }
  return(TRUE)
}
```

If you want to use something like this, you'll probably want to add some input checking to make sure that the input is a data frame, etc, etc.  Also, this function only returns a single boolean value.  If you want it to return a data frame of corresponding boolean values, then feel free to adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  By the way, `is.finite(as.matrix(d))` should do the trick, rather than `as.numeric`.  Your answer could then be extended as `all(is.finite(as.matrix(d)))`.  I'm particularly focused on why I need to wrap this in the first place.  :)  Returning `is.finite(as.matrix(d))` or @DWin's `sapply` method are how I expect to wrap a solution, but the inconsistency piqued my interest.